# Limit Number of Checkboxes Checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with several checkboxes. I have three categories of checkboxes in the form. I need to limit to a max of three checkboxes *per* category.

I used this script but it limits to three checkboxes per form.

```
jQuery(function(){
   var max = 3;
   var checkboxes = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]');

   checkboxes.change(function(){
      var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
       checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
   });
});
```

How do I modify the above script to limit three checkboxes per category within one form?

HTML Example:

```
<!-- FORM CODE --> 

<!-- Start Categories -->

<label>Cat 1</label>
  <!-- Checkboxes for Cat 1 - Max of Three in Category -->
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1" id="CAT_Custom_365571_0" name="CAT_Custom_365571" />Creative<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2" id="CAT_Custom_365571_1" name="CAT_Custom_365571" />Euphoric<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3" id="CAT_Custom_365571_2" name="CAT_Custom_365571" />Uplifted<br />
  <!-- More checkboxes -->
<label>Cat 2</label>
  <!-- Checkboxes for Cat 2 - Max of Three in Category -->
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1" id="CAT_Custom_365572_0" name="CAT_Custom_365572" />Option 1<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2" id="CAT_Custom_365572_1" name="CAT_Custom_365572" />Option 2<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3" id="CAT_Custom_365572_2" name="CAT_Custom_365572" />Option 3<br />
  <!-- More checkboxes -->
<label>Cat 3</label>
  <!-- Checkboxes for Cat 3 - Max of Three in Category -->
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 1" id="CAT_Custom_365573_0" name="CAT_Custom_365573" />Option 1<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 2" id="CAT_Custom_365573_1" name="CAT_Custom_365573" />Option 2<br />
  <input type="checkbox" value="Option 3" id="CAT_Custom_365573_2" name="CAT_Custom_365573" />Option 3<br />
  <!-- More checkboxes -->

<!-- MORE FORM CODE -->
```

Note: The `CAT_Custom_365571_2` etc is generated by the CMS I use.

Comment: can you share the html of the checkboxes as well

Comment: Just should wrap each category in a wrapper, otherwise you'll have to fiddle around with nextUntil and uneccessary complex selectors.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Added some code.

Comment: @Lynda see my answer below

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/48BvH/1 PLEASE CHECK IT, IT DISABLE OTHER CHECKBOXES WHEN LIMIT( MAX = 3) IS CROSSED.

Comment: @softsdev - There is no need to shout. Type normal text. Also you answered, no need to post a fiddle in the comments and in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQUERY

```
$("input[name=chk]").change(function(){
    var max= 3;
    if( $("input[name=chk]:checked").length == max ){
        $("input[name=chk]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("input[name=chk]:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
         $("input[name=chk]").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name"chk" value="A"/>A
<input type="checkbox" name"chk" value="B"/>B
<input type="checkbox" name"chk" value="C"/>C
<input type="checkbox" name"chk" value="D"/>D
<input type="checkbox" name"chk" value="E"/>E
<input type="checkbox" name"chk" value="F"/>F
<input type="checkbox" name"chk" value="F"/>G
```

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE IS HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/48BvH/1)

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve my problem. Your answer shows one category and disables after three checkboxes. I have three categories and the checkboxes are disabled on a per category basis only after three are selected per category.

Comment: @Lynda that answer i was prepared before you send HTML in your answer that's why i consider one scenario and create that code

Answer (score 5):

Try (if your markup matches the one in the fiddle)

```
jQuery(function(){
    var max = 3;
    var checkboxes = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]');

    checkboxes.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var set = $this.add($this.prevUntil('label')).add($this.nextUntil(':not(:checkbox)'));
        var current = set.filter(':checked').length;
        return current <= max;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mh3HS/1/)

Update: 
Since you have a name for the checkboxes

```
jQuery(function(){
    var max = 3;
    var checkboxes = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]');

    checkboxes.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var set = checkboxes.filter('[name="'+ this.name +'"]')
        var current = set.filter(':checked').length;
        return current <= max;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mh3HS/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function(){
   var max = 3;
   var categories = jQuery('label'); // use better selector for categories

   categories.each(function(){
       var checkboxes = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
       checkboxes.change(function(){
            var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
            checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: i like this solution, but this assumes that there will be no checkboxes that won't be limited.

Answer (score 1):

just add a class to all the related check boxes, and just use the class selector when checking the checkboxes for a category.
eg:

**HTML**

```
<label>Cat 1</label>
<input type='checkbox' class='cat1' />
<input type='checkbox' class='cat1' />
<input type='checkbox' class='cat1' />

<label>Cat 2</label>
<input type='checkbox' class='cat2' />
<input type='checkbox' class='cat2' />
<input type='checkbox' class='cat2' />
...
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function(){
   var max = 3;

   var cat1_checkboxes = jQuery('input.cat1[type="checkbox"]');
   var cat2_checkboxes = jQuery('input.cat2[type="checkbox"]');
   var cat3_checkboxes = jQuery('input.cat3[type="checkbox"]');


   cat1_checkboxes.change(function(){
      var current = cat1_checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
       checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
   });

   cat2_checkboxes.change(function(){
      var current = cat2_checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
       checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
   });

   cat3_checkboxes.change(function(){
      var current = cat3_checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
       checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a newbie code **with javascript**. It's like working...hardly...
I call this function on each input.
But there is surely a way to call this function one time.
It's working but uncheking a random checkbox from thoses who call it.

```
   <input type="checkBox"  name="cat1" value="education" onClick="just2cat();">Education
    <input type="checkBox"  name="cat2" value="faith" onClick="just2cat();">Religions
    <input type="checkBox"  name="cat3" value="news" onClick="just2cat();">News



  function just2cat()
        {
            var allInp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            const MAX_CHECK_ = 2; /*How many checkbox could be checked*/
            var nbChk =0;
            for(var i= 0; i<allInp.length; i++)
            {
                if(allInp[i].type.toLowerCase()=='checkbox' && allInp[i].checked) /*OR
                if(allInp[i].type.toLowerCase()=='checkbox' && allInp[i].checked===true) */
                {
                    nbChk++;

                    if(nbChk > MAX_CHECK_) 
                    {
                        alert("At most 2 categories can be chosen");
                        allInp[i].checked=false; /* try to Unchek the current checkbox :'(  */
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```