# Limiting user for number of checkboxes to checked

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, function, checkbox

I am trying to develop a page in which there are many check boxes but user is restricted to check only 2 checkboxes. I got this code but it is not working as i am giving it a name as array. Please suggest how to use this name for check boxes when calling th javascript function.

```js
function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
    var checkgroup=checkgroup;
    var limit=limit;
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
        checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
            var checkedcount=0;
            for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
                checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0;
            if (checkedcount>limit){
                alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes");
                this.checked=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.seatdata, 2);
```

```html
<form id="world" name="world">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|12' id="A11" />
  <label for="A11">A11</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|11' id="A10"  />
  <label for="A10">A10</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|10' id="A9"  />
  <label for="A9">A9</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|9' id="A8"  />
  <label for="A8">A8</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|6' id="A7"  />
  <label for="A7">A7</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|5' id="A6"  />
  <label for="A6">A6</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|4' id="A5"  />
  <label for="A5">A5</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|3' id="A4"  />
  <label for="A4">A4</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|2' id="A3" />
  <label for="A3">A3</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|1' id="A2" />
  <label for="A2">A2</label>
</td>
<td>
  <input type='checkbox' name='seatdata[]' value='0|0' id="A1" unchecked />
  <label for="A1">A1</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit Number of Checkboxes Checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692543/limit-number-of-checkboxes-checked)

Comment: @HudsonPH may not be a duplicate. That was a jquery answer. This one is a pure js question

Comment: @HudsonPH but it jquery i want to do it with javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line

`checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.seatdata, 2);` to `checkboxlimit(document.forms.world["seatdata[]"], 2);`

or use `document.getElementsByName`

`checkboxlimit(document.getElementsByName("seatdata[]"), 2);`

Answer (score 1):

For pure javascript -

```
checkboxlimit(document.getElementsByName("seatdata[]"), 2);
```

For jQuery Users -

HTML code-

```
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" />hello1
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" />hello2
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" />hello3
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" />hello4
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" />hello5
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" />hello6
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" />hello7
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" />hello8
```

Jquery Code-

```
var limit = 2;
var count = 0;
$('.abc').change(function(){
    count++;
    if(count > limit){
      alert("You cant select more than "+limit+" checkboxes");
      this.checked=false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use

```js
checkboxlimit(document.getElementsByName('seatdata[]'), 2);
```